# How to download an online .jpg to the sdcard?

Tags: android, jpeg

I've read some posts about this, but they don't seem to work.

I have an online picture, http://sivo.site90.com/dag_1.jpg

I want to download the picture to the SD card (sdcard/data/data/com.myapp),
show an image view of the saved file, and have the file available later from the SD card for offline viewing.

Does anyone how I can do this?

Comment: Would be easier if you split this into 3 independent problems and try to solve them step by step. 1. Show an image file in an ImageView. 2. Download data using an url. 3. Storing data in a file on the sdcard. It's not that hard.... there are loads of examples.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement. But instead of saving the image in the sd card. I saved it into the sqlite database.

This is the code I use to get the image and save to the bytearray

```
try {
     URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
     URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();

     InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

     ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
     int current = 0;
     while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
         baf.append((byte) current);
     }
     return baf.toByteArray();
} catch (Exception e) {
     Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
}
```

Later you can save this byte array in the database as the type blob.
In this way, user cant delete your image from the sd card.

You can set the byte array to the imageview like this

```
logoImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( currentAccount.accImage, 
        0,currentAccount.accImage.length));
```